# Group Membership of Servers

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to get "WSUS" group membership of my ad computers (servers) in the entire domain.
The PowerShell Script is use:

```
$csvInfos=@()
$allservers=@(Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=BRLN-Servers,OU=OU-BRLN,OU=DE,OU=Locations,DC=bla,DC=bla,DC=bla" -Filter * -Properties *)
foreach($server in $allservers){
                $customobject = new-object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{

                'Servername' = $server.Name
                'WSUS Gruppen' = ($server | get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership |?{$_.Name -like '*wsus*'} | Select-Object Name )
                'OS' = $server.OperatingSystem }

            $csvinfos+= $customobject }

$csvinfos | export-csv c:\temp\wsus_server_groups.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

The Script works ... kinda ok I think but I got some problems with the result.

1. The group names are displayed as `@{Name=Groupname}`, Is it possible that the group name will be displayed as "Groupname"?
2. If a server is in more than 1 "WSUS"-Group I get `System.Object[]`. How can I get all the groups the server is a member of as result?

I think my problems are not that difficult to fix, but I do not have that xp with PowerShell to do it on my own.

Best regards
Michael

***EDIT: ORIGINAL QUESTION IS SOLVED ... BUT HERE IS A NEW PROBLEM!***

The script is used on 3 different domains (US, EU, ASIA) The domain are built the same. Same OU structure, same settings, same everything.

Based on the updated script I am able to get the results I want for 2 of the 3 domains. On the third domain I get an error with the get-adprincipalgroupmembership command:

Get-ADPrincipalGroupmembership : The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.

I googled very much about this error. Even here on stackoverflow is a topic with that error:

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership Fails when any user group name has "/"

but I don't think that is describes the same situation as mine. Or maybe I am blind....

so: Is there a way to fix that problem / error or do I have to use another command that does the same as Get-ADPrincipalGroupmembership?

Thank you, Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use The `-ExpandProperty` parameter for the `Select-Object` property to get the property value without the column header.

See the Differnece:

```
Get-Process explorer | Select Name

Name    
----    
explorer

Get-Process explorer | Select -ExpandProperty Name
explorer
```

2. Join the Multiple results with comma `,` (in case there's only one element, no join occur)

To convert an array to string, you need to parse it in someway, for example join it with commas

Example:

```
1..3 # Array of 3 elements
1
2
3

(1..3).ToString() # Convert it to string will result:
System.Object[]

(1..3 -join ',').ToString() # using join will result:
1,2,3

# for one element, there's no effect:

(1 -join ',').ToString()
1
```

So, update this line to solve both problems:

```
'WSUS Gruppen' = ($server | get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership |?{$_.Name -like '*wsus*'} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name ) -join ','
```